# Underscore findWhere returns nothing, but using find returns data successfully?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm passing an array of models to a method. I am then trying to find the selected model.

I have two means of doing so, both utilizing underscoreJS's functions:

```
var selectedStreamItem = _.find(addedStreamItems, function(streamItem) {
    return streamItem.get('selected');
});

var otherWaySelectedStreamItem = _.findWhere(addedStreamItems, { selected: true });

console.log("selectedStreamItem and otherWaySelectedStreamItem", selectedStreamItem, otherWaySelectedStreamItem);
```

The first function, find, returns the selected model successfully. However, the second returns undefined.

Is this a bug with underscoreJS? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Can you build a fiddle ?

Comment: I can try! I think it might just be because I'm working on an array and not a collection and findWhere is intended only for collections? But I'll see if I can come up with something simple to check.

Comment: `findWhere` does not apply a `get` method, but just checks `streamItem.selected === true`.

Comment: If it's backbone you can use `collection.findWhere({attr: 'value'})`

Comment: Yeah, it was backbone -- it was just after one filter had already been applied -- so I had an array subset of my collection with which I wanted to call findWhere.